# When using Mylyn in Eclipse, why do task context elements not show up in the navigator view?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I've been using Eclipse for many years.  I'm trying to switch into using Mylyn.  I've configured a task and it's automatically added a number of files to the context.  So far, so good.

However, when the "Focus on Active Task" button is enabled/depressed (in the Navigator View), many of the files in the task context are hidden -- I cannot find them unless I turn off "Focus on Active Task" -- which sort of defeats the purpose.

Why are items listed in the Context not being shown in the Navigator View?

Comment: +1 I concur. I'm using Juno and I have the same issue. Sometimes suddenly the files vanish if the 'Focus on active task' is clicked. The focused elements are in bold if we unclick the button, but clicking on it again doesn't help. Restarting eclipse, closing and opening project did not help. Really annoying!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you found a solution for your problem, since this question is quite old, but here is what i just found out. For me the problem only occurs if the "Package Presentation" is set to "Hierarchical". Setting it to "Flat" helps. Sounds like a bug to me and unfortunately i prefer the hierarchical view.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there are two questions here:

1. Why are only some files in my context showing when I select "Focus on Active Task"?
2. How can I view files not in my context when I've selected "Focus on Active Task"?

For item one, Mylyn records every file you touch when working on a task and stores it as part of the task context (see note at end).    For large tasks it quickly becomes useless to see *every* file that you've touched and so Mylyn uses an algorithm to decide which files are most relevant to your task, based on how many times you've viewed and edited them.  Thus, when you select "Focus on Active Task" only the most relevant files are shown.

For item two, it is often the case that you'd want to view files that are not shown as part of your context while "Focus on Active Task" is selected, and Mylyn provides a way of doing this.  You can view all children files of a visible node by holding down ALT while clicking on that node.  The files will become visible temporarily.  Similarly, if you do not have any files showing in context you can hold ALT and click in the Package Explorer (or other view of the project) and it will show all files.  ALT + clicking is an essential action for anyone who wants to work with their PackageExplorer focused.

The 2.5 minute video [Get Task-Focused](http://tasktop.com/videos/1.6/setup/focus/) will help you better understand how focusing the Package Explorer is intended to be used.

---

[David Shepherd](http://www.twitter.com/davidcshepherd)
 Tasktop Technologies, Inc.

*Note: You can see every file that is in your context by opening the task editor, selecting the "Context" tab (at the bottom), and then sliding the "Actions" slider to the left.*

Comment: Nope. Absolutely not my question.  I understand Mylyn, and I've been using it for a while now.  For the most part, it's been working great.

My question was this: "why do task context elements not show up in the navigator view."

When I go to the task context, these files are _in_the_context_.  However, they don't show up in the navigator (unless, of course, I disable "focus on the active task", which defeats the purpose).

Comment: Desau,
Sorry I misinterpreted your question! Task context elements should show up in the navigator view.  If they are not showing up in the navigator view then you are encountering a serious bug.  If you can post a concrete example I can try to replicate it, but I am currently working on a task and am viewing relevant files in the Navigator View with no problem.  Let me know if you're still having problems.
Cheers,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Even in Eclipse Luna 4.4 the [described limitation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mylyn.help.ui%2FMylyn%2FFAQ%2FJava-Development.html) exists: project explorer package presentation *has to be set to flat*.

"Known limitations - Bug 106678: The Project Explorer’s Hierarchical Java package presentation layout is not supported on Eclipse 3.3Mx, and interesting elements will be hidden if enabled. Work-around is to use the default Flat package presentation."

(replace "Eclipse 3.3Mx"  by "Eclipse >= 3.3Mx" and then it makes sense)

Yes, this bug is getting 10 years old ;-)